# Interval of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}9(-1)^nnx^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find the interval and radius of convergence and I'm really confused with what I'm supposed to be doing.  Here is the problem:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}9(-1)^nnx^n$

I then used the ratio test to get $|9||x|\lt1$ and took a guess at my interval of convergence as $-\frac{1}{9}$ and $\frac{1}{9}$

Am I on the right track and if so what do I do from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $9$ is irrelevant, it is a constant.  The ratio of the absolute values of the terms is $$\left|\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{nx^{n}}\right|\to|x|$$

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\sim$?

Comment: @user1337 Ah, yes.

Comment: What about the radius of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to find the radius of convergence for a power series $\sum a_n(x-p)^n$ is to find
$$\rho = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| $$
and then the power series will converge for $|x-p|<\rho$.

In your case $p=0$ and $a_n = 9n(-1)^n$, and hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{9(n+1)(-1)^{n+1}}{9n(-1)^n} \right| = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left| \frac{n+1}{n} \right|=1$$
That means that your series converges for all $|x|<1$, i.e. $-1 < x< 1$.

Comment: How did you determine $|x|\lt1$ specifically the $\lt1$ portion because I know how you got the rest.

Comment: As I said in the post: $\rho$ is the radius of convergence. It is calculated by taking the limit of $|a_{n+1}/a_n|$ as $n \to \infty$. In your case $\rho = 1$ and $p=0$ so $|x-p|<\rho$ becomes $|x| < 1$.